# Is this wiring up to code and safe?

Tags: electrical

I'm building a reclaimed wood wall to that'll be behind my entertainment center. Can someone please review what I've done with the electric and let me know if anything is unsafe or not up to code?

Is it okay that some of the romex sheathing is cut outside of the junction box (picture 1)?

I had to extend the original outlets and switches from the original wall a few inches to the surface of the new wall - is it okay to have wires going between the two junction boxes without any sheathing? (picture 2)?[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By code the sheath of the romex should be 1/4" inside the box. The open junction behind the new box or the original box what looks to be just conductors running to the new box would also be a code violation. To bring this up to code A cover plate with holes and clamps wounded be needed on the old box then short pieces of romex with the sheaths entering the boxes 1/4" would meet code requirements. If there is not enough room for all the splices a box extension on the old box could be used some box extensions have knockouts on the side this would be easier to wire and clamp than clamps on the cover if the space in the old box is tight.